# [: : integer expression expected bash script

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu

I keep getting a [: -ge: unary operator expected and [: -gt: unary operator expected. Not sure what the deal is. I have tried putting the variable in quotation and then I get [: : integer expression expected. Here is my script:

```
    #!/bin/bash
read -p "How big is the compressed file size in bytes?: "$file_size;

if [ $file_size" -lt 5000 ]
then
    echo "The compression ratio is 90%"

elif [ $file_size -ge 5000 ] && [ "$file_size" -le 50000 ]
then
    echo "The compression ratio is 70%"

elif [ $file_size -gt 50000 ]
then
    echo "The compresison ratio is 40%"
fi
```

Comment: Remove stray `"` from `[ $file_size" -lt 5000 ]`

Comment: No, add the missing `"` prior to `$file_size`.

Comment: You have multiple problems in the posted code; check http://shellcheck.net.

Comment: Ever heard about syntax highlighting?

Comment: When you first test the under and upper boundaries, than you do not need to specify the boundaries for 70%. You might want to consider a switch statement `case (( $file_size / 5000 )) in ...` with cases `1)`, `[2-9])` and `*)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line

```
read -p "How big is the compressed file size in bytes?: "$file_size;
```

has multiple problems. First, you need a space between the `-p` argument and the variable "name" (more on that in a bit):

```
read -p "How big is the compressed file size in bytes?: " $file_size;
```

Second, the name should not be prefixed with a `$` (unless `file_size` contains the name of the variable yo want to set).

```
read -p "How big is the compressed file size in bytes?: " file_size
```

As written, your `read` statement isn't given a name to set, so it defaults to `$REPLY`. This means that `file_size` has no value.